# Square Matrices Interpretation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

I am currently stuck on the following problem. I have never seen a syntax like this. Could someone explain me what is going on. Why is my determinant equal to four squares (the A matrix, the 0 matrix, the negative identity matrix, and my B matrix). What does the cross dividing them unto four squares mean. How am I supposed to interpret this?

If I read the theorem correctly: It says that the determinant of the dot product between two matrices is equal to the dot product of two matrices.

I know how to calculate a calculate a 2x2 matrix or 3x3, but I find this too theoretical.

Sorry for the confusion, thank you for any answers or tips.

[image]

Comment: The "dot" product between two matrices?  This is ordinary multiplication here.

Comment: I am sorry, but I really don't understand what is going on.

Comment: As for the "cross dividing them into four squares" that is merely there for having a graphical way of viewing the fact that things are organized nicely.  It is [block matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix).  They have no mathematical meaning and are only there for organization.  They can be removed and the meaning will be the same.

Comment: Thank you. I would really love to understand this. Does the theorem then say that the determinant of the product between two matrices is the same as the product of the determinant of two matrices?

Comment: Yes.  The theorem does indeed say that $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$, and presumably goes on to provide a proof, one that uses a block matrix where the top left quarter of the entries are what you would have seen for matrix $A$, the bottom right for $B$, top-right all zero, and bottom-left quarter the negative identity.  Continuing to scroll you should see the proof continue.